# Epoch_to_date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

It seems as though the epoch_to_date function is adding some hours to the date I pass. Can anyone point out what am I missing here ? I am converting a date to epoch and converting back to date expecting to get the same value I passed. But I am getting a different value.

When I run the following query in my Db,

```
select epoch_to_date(to_epoch(to_date('07/31/2014 10:35:46','mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'))) from dual;
```

The output is

```
  EPOCH_TO_DATE(TO_EP
  -------------------
  31/07/2014 17:35:46
```

Not understanding why 7 hrs got added to my date. Please help.

Comment: `to_epoch` and `epoch_to_date` are not standard Oracle functions. Please show us the code for those functions

Comment: Thanks, Got the issue. I was under impression that epoch_to_date and to_epoch functions were standard oracle functions.

Answer (score 0):

`Epoch_to_Date` gives you the date in GMT format. Hence it is 7 hrs ahead, please convert accordingly by using `new_time` function.

Please refer below.

```
to_char(new_time(epoch_to_date(CREATE_DATE),'GMT','PDT'),'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
CREATE_DATE
```